# "using" type alias of class scope: [when] can usages in methods PRECEDE the type alias?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, type-alias

Yesterday, I was (pleasantly) surprised when I was able to compile code that had a method which used a [using type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) even though the declaration of the alias was not until later in the class definition.

- Is this 'forward' usage of a type-alias valid? (I assume it is, since Clang 5 and GCC 4.9 both work this way.)
- What rules cover this behavior and the difference between the method body and method signature usages?

**Case #1 - using declared after method, valid inside method body (only?)**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct X {
  std::string create() {     // fails to compile if Y used in signature
      return Y{"hello!"};    // compiles when Y here
  }

  using Y = std::string;     // declared at bottom
};

int main() 
{
    std::cout << X().create() << std::endl;
}
```

**Case #2 - using declared above is [also] valid in signature**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct X {
  using Y = std::string;     // declared at top

  Y create() {               // can use Y here as well
      return Y{"hello!"};
  }
};

int main() 
{
    std::cout << X().create() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure there is a dupe somewhere, but it's because a function body is a [complete-class context](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#6).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has to do with the [*complete-class context*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#mem-7).  When you are in the body of a member function, the class is considered complete and can use anything defined in the class, no matter where in the class it is declared.

The return type of a member function is not part of the *complete-class context* so you can only use names that are known about at that point in the code.

Comment: Note: This term was only introduced in C++20, but the same concept applies before that.