# C++ enum declaration after use in class

Tags: c++, class, enums, member

I tried to create a class with an enum, and a function that returns a variable of this enum. But I ran into a problem:

This works:

```
class SizeBoxClass {

public:
    enum BoxType{xBox, yBox};

    BoxType intersects() {
        return xBox;
    }

}SizeBox;
```

But this does not:

```
class SizeBoxClass {

public:
    BoxType intersects() {
        return xBox;
    }

    enum BoxType { xBox, yBox };

}SizeBox;
```

I get "BoxType is undefined" at the line of the function declaration...
Why? I thought declaring a class member after its use was not a problem.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60155508/using-type-alias-of-class-scope-when-can-usages-in-methods-precede-the-type.  Trying to see if there is a better one

Comment: In C++ types have to be declared before you use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enum BoxType { xBox, yBox };` is a *type declaration* (and also *definition*), not a member variable or member function.

Types need to be declared before first use.

Comment: *Types need to be declared before first use.* Kind of.  `class SizeBoxClass {

public:
    auto intersects() {
        return BoxType{};
    }

    enum BoxType { xBox, yBox };

}SizeBox;` Is legal and "uses" the type before it is declared

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, there is that odd corner where you declare a member variable of the type at the same time. Good point. Got a standard quote that specifies why this variant is legal?