# What is the order of control flow while compiling the code for a class in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, control-flow, access-specifier

I am compiling a class, the complete program to which is given below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test{
    public:
        Test()
        {
            cout<<"Test variable created...\n";
            // accessing width variable in constructor
            cout<<"Width is "<<width<<".\n";
        }
        void setHeight(int h)
        {
            height = h;
        }
        void printHeight()
        {
            cout<<"Height is "<<height<<" meters.\n";
        }
        int width = 6;
    protected:
        int height;
};

int main()
{
    Test t = Test();
    t.setHeight(3);
    t.printHeight();
    return 0;
}
```

The code works absolutely fine, but how is the constructor able to access the variable `width` which has not been declared until the end of `public` block. Also, how are the member functions able to access the variables declared later in the public block? Isn't C++ sequential (executing the statements in the order they are written)?

Comment: Declarations are not statements. A class's declarations are collected and stored before trying to compile its code. Also, statements needn't be executed sequentially iff the observable behaviour of the program would be the same, AFAIK, under the 'as-if' rule.

Comment: _"Isn't C++ sequential (executing the statements in the order they are written)?"_ No, it's not. Statements can be executed in different order, e.g. member initializer lists. The statements are executed in the order the members are listed in the class and not in the order of the actual statements.

Comment: Declare as `int height{};` so that users can't invoke undefined behaviour by trying to `printHeight()` without having `setHeight()`.

Comment: Member variables are initialized (`int width = 6;`) before the constructor is called. That means that the structure of the class has to be known before the first non-static method can be called.

Comment: [Here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/cplr389.htm) you can see what happens before the actual constructor starts its work. There are better documentations for this but I wasn't able to find them.

Comment: sorta-duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60155508/using-type-alias-of-class-scope-when-can-usages-in-methods-precede-the-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of inline definitions in a class as just syntactic sugar for declaring the function, and then defining outside of the class.  Manually doing that would transform the code to

```
class Test{
    public:
        Test();
        void setHeight(int h);
        void printHeight();
        int width = 6;
    protected:
        int height;
};

Test::Test()
{
    cout<<"Test variable created...\n";
    // accessing width variable in constructor
    cout<<"Width is "<<width<<".\n";
}

void Test::setHeight(int h)
{
    height = h;
}

void Test::printHeight()
{
    cout<<"Height is "<<height<<" meters.\n";
}
```

And you can see from this transformation that the class member is now "before" the function definitions, so there is no reason why they can't know about the variable.

The technical term for this is call the [complete-class context](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class#mem.general-7) and the jist of it is that when you are in the body of a member function or the class member initialization list, the class is considered complete and can use anything defined in the class, no matter where in the class it is declared.

Comment: Is it also true in the initializer list of a constructor ?

Comment: @VincentFourmond Yes.  The member initialization list is consider part of the function body

Comment: Thanks @NathanOlivier I guess it would be a valuable precision in your answer ?

Comment: @VincentFourmond added.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the body of a member function is a **complete-class context** of a class, as mentioned in the quoted statements below:

From [class.mem.general#6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.mem.general#6):

> **6.** A complete-class context of a class is a:
>
> - **function body** ([dcl.fct.def.general]),
> - default argument,
> - noexcept-specifier ([except.spec]), or
> - default member initializer
>
> within the member-specification of the class.

The above means that a function body is a complete-class context of a class which in turn means that the usage of `width` inside the constructor and the usage of `height` inside member function `setHeight` and `printHeight` is allowed here even though those data members appear later when writing the class definition.